# Parsing Dublin Core data

Tags: ios

How do I parse Dublin Core data in iOS? The data is like this:

```
dc:contributor          Binder, Henry.
dc:creator          Crane, Stephen, 1871-1900.
dc:date         c1982
dc:description          This stirring tale of action in the American Civil War       captures the immediacies and experiences of actual battle and army life.
dc:format           ix, 173 p. ; 22 cm.
dc:identifier           0393013456
dc:identifier           9780393013450
dc:identifier           0380641135 (pbk.)
dc:identifier           9780380641130 (pbk.)
dc:language         eng
dc:publisher            Norton
dc:subject          Chancellorsville, Battle of, Chancellorsville, Va., 1863--Fiction.
dc:subject          Virginia--History--Civil War, 1861-1865--Fiction.
dc:title            The red badge of courage : an episode of the American Civil War
dc:type         War stories.
dc:type         Historical fiction.
dc:type         Text
oclcterms:recordCreationDate            811217
oclcterms:recordIdentifier           81022419
oclcterms:recordIdentifier          8114241
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data structure structure has a predictable format, ie each line has a clear tag and then a tab-like space.

Hence if you are familiar with the tag names you can definitely create a small program to consume each line accordingly.